# What is the optimal pO2 concentration for automated reactor batch mode EColi expression?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, microbiology, proteins, protein-expression

I am wondering what is the optimal pO2 level for an reactor based expression? All protocols I have found indicate for E.Coli pO2 levels just bigger 20%. So, I am wondering what is the optimal level? As a rule of thumb?  I guess Iower 20 % is bad because it will limit growth. On the other hand I would assume too much oxygen will also be harmfull for E. Coli. Which level is too high? 40, 80, 100 %? Or is as high as possible always best? I would check this with an OD curve, right? What would happen to an culture when the oxygen is too low (1-2 % ?) for an longer amount of time? Would the bacteria just die or just decrease in activity? In my current culture I used TB media with Bl21 3DE at pH 7 and 37 degrees.. Oygen levels were controlled by gasmix, gas flow and stirrer speed.